# How do I unset a Docker image label?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've a Dockerfile starting with the [official nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/).

```
FROM nginx
```

And they set the [maintainer label](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/f603bb3632ea6df0bc9da2179c18eb322c286298/mainline/stretch/Dockerfile#L3).

```
LABEL maintainer="NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
```

So, now my image appears to also be maintained by them.

```
$ docker image inspect example-nginx
...
        "Labels": {
            "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
        },
```

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label) [mentions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-metadata-on-container--l---label---label-file) how to overwrite the label. But, so far, the best I can do is set it to an empty value.

```
LABEL maintainer=
```

```
$ docker image inspect example-nginx
...
        "Labels": {
            "maintainer": ""
        },
```

How do I completely *remove* or *unset* a label set by a parent image?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Great question. I did some research and, as far as I know, it's not possible with the current Docker/Moby implementation. It's also a problem for other properties as well, as you can see here (the issue is from 2014!):

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465

I know it's really annoying, but, if you really want to remove that you can try following this:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465#issuecomment-383416201

The person automatized this process with a `Python` script that seems to let you do what you want:

https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit

It appears to have the **Remove Label** operation (https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-copyedit/blob/92091ed4d7a91fda2de39eb3ded8dd280fe61a35/docker-copyedit.py#L304), that is what you want.

I don't know if it works (I haven't had time to test that), but I think it's worth trying.