# How to NOT inherit labels from base images in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-build

When a docker image X is used as the base image for docker image Y, image Y inherits all of X's labels. That is, image Y has all the labels of X plus any labels Y adds.

Is there any way to prevent this label inheritance from happening, either in the Dockerfile or in the `docker build` command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I unset a Docker image label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978051/how-do-i-unset-a-docker-image-label)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to remove labels. I'm using my own 'namespace' when I add labels in my image so that I can find the ones I want easily later. Example label can be `com.mycompanyname.foo` set to value `bar`.